# SpriteKit SKShapeNode intersects not accurate

Tags: swift3, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skshapenode

I have created a circle using SKShapeNode.

I then try to check if a second node intersects the SKShapeNode above.

However, I am getting intersects = true even when my second node is still outside of the circle itself.

Here is the code that I used to initialise the SKShapeNode:

```
let background = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius = 330)
background.position = CGPoint(x: size.width * 0.5, y: size.height * 0.5)
background.fillColor = UIColor(red:0.57, green:0.57, blue:0.57, alpha:0.6)
background.strokeColor = .red//UIColor(red:0.57, green:0.57, blue:0.57, alpha:0.6)
addChild(background)
```

Comment: SKShapeNode is known to be buggy and have problems.  You should avoid using it wherever possible.

Comment: what does "intersects = true" mean,  you need to actually show this code

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the `SKNode().intersects` method.

The [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode/1483140-intersects) says

> The two nodes are considered to intersect if their frames intersect.

The frame is a bounding box around your circular SKShapeNode, which is why the `intersects` method returns true even though the node does not intersect the circle itself.